# By passing CORS (AJAX & XML) with Google Search Appliance

Tags: ajax, xml, cors, google-search-appliance

We are currently implementing the search appliance for one of our newly redesigned website. The solution designed involves in making AJAX calls to the search appliance to pull suggestions and search results. The suggestions work well as expected but the search results are running into CORS issue.

Technically the website and search appliance belong to the same domain but different subdomains. Is there any way within the GSA console to allow requests from another domain or any subdomain belonging to the same domain as the GSA?

Forex : From web.example.com To gsa.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a [HA Proxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) in front of the GSA.

Configure it to set the below HTTP header in the response. See this [example](http://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/http_rewriting.html#set-a-header-in-the-response) to set custom headers.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This is the only way you can resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Vinay, Im talking to our network team to get this done. I feel there should be a way in the GSA to be able to manage this and allow the trust between two. I found something related to kerberos token to establish trust between two domains. Have you explored this option?

Comment: No, I have not explored any Kerberos alternative. Let me know how you progress with that.

Answer (score 1):

For the suggest service you can use jsonp by adding :

&callback=your_callback_method

For the search you have to stick with a proxy solution as mentionned by Vinay.